# How to iterate child arrays as "rows" of parent array, while (by name) echoing values (of key/value pairs) in each "row"

Tags: php, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I've spent hours and hours searching and trying. Based on the documentation for array() and list() it seems one of my variations could work, but no success so far.

My goal is that the following code (or some corrected version of it)...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Demo of Issue</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php   

$Details_Standard_Ship = Array ( 
    Array ('Book_ID' => 'c7xhGSU', 'Author_Name' => 'John Doe', 'Language' => 'English', 'Title' => 'Some Title 1'),
    Array ('Book_ID' => 'rFxW8Bo', 'Author_Name' => 'Jane Doe', 'Language' => 'Spanish', 'Title' => 'Some Title 2')
);

foreach ($Details_Standard_Ship as $Details_ITEM) {

    list($_Book_ID, $_Author_Name, $_Language, $_Title) = current($Details_ITEM); 

    echo "<p>Book_ID = " . $_Book_ID . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Author_Name = " . $_Author_Name . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Language = " . $_Language . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Title = " . $_Title . "</p>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

...will output this result:

Iteration 1 of 2 (first child array)

`Book_ID: c7xhGSU, Author_Name: John Doe, Language: English, Title: Some Title 1`

Iteration 2 of 2 (second child array)

`Book_ID: rFxW8Bo, Author_Name: Jane Doe, Language: Spanish, Title: Some Title 2`

NOTE: at the parent-level of iterating through the parent array, I need each child array to be iterated once, giving a total of main iterations that matches the number of child arrays. The challenge is getting all that child's values while in only one "parent level" iteration of that child array. It seems I need inner loop iterations while doing outer loop iterations. I just don't know how!

Below are pseudo versions of what I've tried ...

```
foreach $Details_Standard_Ship as $Details_ITEM {
  foreach $Details_ITEM as list($_Book_ID, $_Author_Name, $_Language, $_Title) {
  // echoing here...
  }
}
```

and

```
foreach ($Details_Standard_Ship as $Details_ITEM) {
  list($_Book_ID, $_Author_Name, $_Language, $_Title) = current($Details_ITEM); 
  // echoing here...
}
```

and

```
foreach ($Details_Standard_Ship as list( $_Book_ID, $_Author_Name, $_Language, $_Title)) {
  // echoing here...
}
```

..and etc.

I sure would welcome and appreciate any help.

Comment: The list() in this case does not work if you dont have PHP >= 7.1.0. Before PHP 7.1.0, list() only worked on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.

Comment: Yes, I was aware, and I'm on PHP 7.3. However,  I had only switched to trying to use list() because my first efforts to use `$array['keyname']`  were not working. There must have been something wrong with the way I was trying, because `$array['keyname']`  is working now. List() seemed to work but not on the right nesting level.

Comment: Ok good you solved it. If you're satisfied with @Supercool answer accept it :-)

Comment: I have upvoted Supercool's answer. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: You could accept the answer by clicking the checkmark below the up/down-vote arrows. That's saying: "Hi I've got my answer and I'm satisified now". If you don't do that more people would try to help you further and it would be wasted time for all if you're satisfied.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: Thanks. I'm new, and I did not know that was something to do. Appreciate it!

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: I've asked (in comments) the same above question (is there more I need to do?) about 4 or 5 times already, and you're the first to explain it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To achieve output posted on question**

Use

```
foreach(array as $key => $value)
    //do something
```

Whole code

```
$Details_Standard_Ship = Array ( 
        Array ('Book_ID' => 'c7xhGSU', 'Author_Name' => 'John Doe', 'Language' => 'English', 'Title' => 'Some Title 1'),
        Array ('Book_ID' => 'rFxW8Bo', 'Author_Name' => 'Jane Doe', 'Language' => 'Spanish', 'Title' => 'Some Title 2')
 );

 foreach ($Details_Standard_Ship as $Details_ITEM) {
      foreach ($Details_ITEM as $key => $value) {
        echo "<p> $key = $value </p>";
      }
 }
```

**After kinda understanding the problem from comments**

Use `$array['keyname']` to get value of particular key

```
   $Details_Standard_Ship = Array ( 
            Array ('Book_ID' => 'c7xhGSU', 'Author_Name' => 'John Doe', 'Language' => 'English', 'Title' => 'Some Title 1'),
            Array ('Book_ID' => 'rFxW8Bo', 'Author_Name' => 'Jane Doe', 'Language' => 'Spanish', 'Title' => 'Some Title 2')
     );

     foreach ($Details_Standard_Ship as $Details_ITEM) {
        echo "<p>Book_ID = " .  $Details_ITEM['Book_ID'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Author_Name = " . $Details_ITEM['Author_Name']  . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Language = " . $Details_ITEM['Language']  . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Title = " . $Details_ITEM['Title']  . "</p>"; 
     }
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to be able to output a detailed table, and echo certain values in certain TD elements in the table, all while in the same "master iteration" of the given "row" of the child array. So, I cannot see how that type of approach would work. It iterates through each value of a child row, instead only iterating the child row once.

Comment: im not able to get you.Whatever you have mentioned about the desired output , my solution should produce the desired output

Comment: Put another way, I have (above) only two rows, not eight rows. I need a way to iterate those two rows, and while in any one such iteration, echo out all the child row values at once by name.

Comment: For the first of two iterations, which would be [0], but I'll call it 'Book_ID' => 'c7xhGSU', I need to call on all the values in that row at the same time, hopefully by name. Then repeat for the second row. Iterating through all the values as rows, gives me way too many rows.

Comment: So do you mean you want get only one key's value for example only author name?

Comment: if you can add the input and desired output then i can figure out the problem

Comment: Thanks again. Put another way, all the values, combined, form only one row (a whole child array is a row). During the iteration of that one row, some of its values will be needed, while some will not be needed, and some calculations will be needed on some values, others not.

Comment: Here's an example of only one portion of out put while in one iteration of a given child array. I need to be able to "arbitrarily" call on any of the child array's values while in the "master iteration" of that row (that child array):

Comment: ```                <?php echo "<img class=\"cart-thumb\" align=\"left\" src='"?> <?php if (!$Custom_Domain_Enabled) { echo "_master/"; } ?> <?php echo "_domains/" . $_Cover_Front_Thumb . "'> " . $_Print_Binding_Type . " - " . $_Title; ?> <?php if( $_Subtitle  <> "" ) { echo ": " . $_Subtitle; } ?> (Domestic Standard Shipping)
```

Comment: im confused for example you want to only see author names you can check if key value is author and then echo it foreach ($Details_ITEM as $key => $value) {
       if($key=='Author_Name') echo "<p> $key = $value </p>";
      }

Comment: I guess I'm looking at the iteration generations wrongly. I guess I need "parent iterations" and then child iterations (loop within a loop) to assign values, which get used outside the inner loop, in the outer loop. I'm trying to get my head around it!

Comment: I guess what I need is .. "while in a parent-level iteration" ... loop through the child array's values, assigning them to vars with names matching the keys, and then use them in the structure, before ending the "parent-level iteration."

Comment: This conversation has been helpful in reshaping my thinking. Basically I'm moving all my output structure outside the first lower "ending bracket" instead of above it. :-)

Comment: Can I replace this, "$key => $value", with list versions of both? Like this? (See below.)

Comment: foreach ($Details_Standard_Ship as $Details_ITEM) {
 foreach $Details_ITEM as list($_Book_ID, $_Author_Name, $_Language, $_Title) => list($_Book_ID_value, $_Author_Name_value, $_Language_value, $_Title_value) {
 }
 // echo here... 
}

Comment: I added to the question, something along these lines: at the parent-level of iterating through the parent array, I need each child array to be iterated once, giving a total of main iterations that matches the number of child arrays. The challenge is getting all that child's values while in only one "parent level" iteration of that child array. It seems I need inner loop iterations while doing outer loop iterations. I just don't know how to assign values in an inner loop, to variables usable outside an inner loop.

Comment: i have edit my answer , check if it answers your problem

Comment: — Your comment with the following helped me get a solution, as follows! (I will post as an answer if I should, but I'd like to credit you. I guess I will upvote the answer you gave, though what I'm doing is a combination of that and the help in your comment!)

Comment: Quote @Supercool: "you can check if key value is author and then echo it foreach ($Details_ITEM as $key => $value) { if($key=='Author_Name') echo "<p> $key = $value </p>"; }"

Comment: Did you check updated solution. This should work for you

Comment: I upvoted the answer by Supercool. Apparently I'm still a little too new for my upvote to show!

Comment: For what it's worth, the very first thing I had tried was `$array['keyname']` — however, it did not work for me then. I now see it does work for me, and there must have been something else wrong with my code! Thank you!!!!!